# Can you have just one WCF service with static methods?

Tags: wcf

I have a misconception about WCF services (I think)
Can you have just one instance of the WCF service that all calls would go too? It seems I am limited to having to create instances of WCF class every time I need to call it.
If I can, do I have to make it static somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanna do is to make a wcf services singleton.

Check [this](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Queued-Services/Instance-Management/) article.

Answer (score 1):

On the server-side, yes, an instance of your service is created for every request / transaction.

On the client-side, you should almost never try to reuse your proxy class. Instantiate, connect, call (you can even call multiple times in a loop), dispose.

Comment: Interesting. This has been my approach but more due to trial and error than an understanding of the connection pool internals. Can you elaborate on why this works and why "you should almost never try to reuse"?